# PyQt - Qprocess Can not run command "chcp" directly but from batch its fine

Tags: qt, python-3.x, cmd, pyqt5, qprocess

The following code working for executing the batch file:

```
def GetCMD_Encoding(self):

    self.CMD = QProcess(self)
    self.CMD.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
    self.CMD.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.EventDataForGetCMDEncoding)
    self.CMD.start("chcp.bat")

def EventDataForGetCMDEncoding(self):
    output = bytearray(self.CMD.readAllStandardOutput())
    output = output.decode("ascii")
    print (output)
```

The content of .bat file is only :

```
chcp
```

But if i want to exclude but file and i only execute simple command like:

```
self.CMD.start("chcp")
```

it does not working and any kind of signal isnt emit.

Other commands is working like :

```
self.CMD.start("ipconfig")
self.CMD.start("help")
```

Comment: Possibly the executable `chcp` is in your `PATH`, whereas the file `chcp.bat` is not (or not executable).

Comment: But `chcp` is standard `CMD` command accesing wthout any path

Comment: Yes because it is in the system PATH. Try with the full path to the bat file. If it works, then you must add this file path to your system PATH.

Comment: yep you were right, the `self.CMD.start("C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com")` is working fine!

Comment: Do not name batch files like internal or external `cmd` commands (like `chcp` in your case)!

Comment: chcp and chcp.bat are easily recognized but nevermind that was just for test :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to

- Use the full path of the file `chcp.bat`
- Or add the path of the file `chcp.bat` to your system PATH

and maybe ensure that the file is executable.

Comment: @ErikŠťastný Yep that's me, providing an answer instead of the comment ;)

Comment: Ahh i am blind :)